# Django ModelForm with ManyToManyField wont save to DB

Tags: django, django-forms, widget

I`m using Django 1.9 with the following:

views.py:

```
def a_new(request):
    # submit button
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('ui:config-list')
    # first visit
    else:
        form = AForm()

    template = 'api/test_template.html'
    context = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
    return render_to_response(template, context)
```

forms.py:

```
class AForm(forms.ModelForm):

     b= forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
         queryset=B.objects.all(),
         widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("b", is_stacked=False)
     )

     class Meta:
         model = A
         fields = ('name', 'b', )
```

test_template.html

```
...
<form role="form" class="form-inline" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        {{ form.name }}
        {{ form.b }}
    </div>


    <div class="dl-horizontal">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

models.py:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B, null=True, blank=True, name='b')
 ...
```

The problem is that when I use the Save button - only the name field is created in the item. The b item, that the widget is being used on, is just not being saved to the DB with the new item A created(it does show error if I leave the b field empty so I guess its checking it too).

What can be the problem?

Comment: Did you tried to check that data is coming for field "b". Try form.cleaned_data.get('b')

Comment: Where should I try it? In the view?

Comment: What debugging tool are you using? If you are using ipdb you can put this line "import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()" below form.is_valid() check. Then you can try that out in your console where your server is running. If you don't have ipdb, just install it, it's a great tool for debugging.

Comment: If the object of Model A is not saved before adding the M2M objects to it, then the M2M objects added to that particular object of Model A won't be saved. Though i'm not sure if this is the problem in your case.
See this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) about using `commit=False` when you have a many-to-many field.

Note that there is no reason for you to be using commit=False here though. Remove it, and the second save, and Django will save your values directly.

Comment: I deleted the two save() lines replacing it with "form.save()". Worked!

Answer (score 0):

b is ManyToManyField, it does on saved on the table A. In a different table the relation between A and B is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an M2M field and do save(commit=False) you need to call this at the end:

```
form.save_m2m()
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).